# What are the steps to solve this limit $\lim _{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x+\pi/2)}x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{x}\right)\:$

Comment: do you know the rules of L'Hospital?

Comment: A very good first step would be $\cos(x+\pi/2)=-\sin x$...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No I don't

Comment: @user283144 It's good that you don't. It's a lousy way to do this.

Answer (score 10):

$\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sin(x)$

So $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\sin(x)}{x}=-1$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$
\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=-\sin x
$$ then your limit is equal to
$$
-\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)=?
$$ which is easier to obtain.

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion which may work more generally (although the above solutions are better in this case) is to apply L'Hôpital's Rule for an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. That is, in this case, the limit of the derivatives of the numerator and denominator is equal to the limit of the original expression:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}{1}=\lim_{x\to0}-\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})=-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=-1.$$

The same result as in the other answers. Use this technique any time you have an indeterminate form.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}{x}\right)=$$
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=$$
$$-\left(\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=$$
$$-\left(\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\sin(x)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}x}\right)=$$
$$-\left(\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{1}\right)=$$
$$-\left(\lim _{x\to 0}\cos(x)\right)=$$
$$-\left(\cos(0)\right)=$$
$$-\left(1\right)=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For acute angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$, use the law of cosines to show that
$$\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$$

Then, use this identity to show that
$$\cos\bigg(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg) = -\sin x$$
and, finally evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin x}{x} = \dots$$